# Information Gathering on Dynamic Website Building & choosing its Architecture

Tags: java, php, mysql, linux

I wanted to build a dynamic Website. The Architecture that I am planning to have is Linux+Apache+MySQL+JSP/Java/Servlets. I have heard a great deal about LAMP stack, but i dont know PHP. Please cite some differences between the two architectures in terms of scalability, security, code re-use, and stuff etc.

Also, having said all this, i need to know where could i get started from. any case-study that could give me an insight as to how to go about building a complete dynamic website.

Thanks.

Comment: This question is far too general. Please try to provide more informations on what kind of website you are trying to build. Without more information, it will be very hard to give you a better answer than what Google will give you.

Comment: This is the link for php http://w3schools.com/php/default.asp

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: Architecture isn't about languages, it is about usages. You can make a really slow, non-scalable, insecure, kludgy mess of java just as easily as PHP.

That said.

PHP is a traditionally less structured language. It is not type safe, and that is a double-edged sword, not a negative. My advice, as always, is to stick with what you know for anything mission critical. But if you want to fool around with PHP, the best way is to install it and start playing.

Good resources are this site, and php.net. And google. PHP has a huge hacker culture around it, you'll find loads of info about just about every possible topic. Good, bad, and all in between.

EDIT::

One thing I would do is avoid learning a framework first. Learn raw, un-cut PHP first.

Comment: I'm sure, but I don't attack problems from that angle. I'm more on the being the first to do it side of wed dev.